# SpingMVC: org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder not found

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

When I include the line
`<mvc:annotation-driven />` in the following

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.skyscraper.controller" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder
```

when running my application.

**POM.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.skyscraper</groupId>
<artifactId>skyscraper-api</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>skyscraper-api</
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <my.version>0.1.0</my.version>
</properties><build>

<finalName>ROOT</finalName>

<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.7</source>
      <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-file</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <configuration>
                <file>${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</file>
                <generatePom>false</generatePom>
                <pomFile>pom.xml</pomFile>
                <version>${my.version}</version>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

       <!-- Spring framework --> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- JSTL --> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- for compile only, your container should have this -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Jackson JSON -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.7</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring Security module --> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>

<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<packaging>war</packaging>
</project>
```

**Stack Trace**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/i18n/LocaleContextHolder
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:949)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:949)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Can I still use `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in Spring4 or am I missing something else?

Comment: Please add the actual stack trace and also your dependencies (pom). First fix your xml file you are mixing spring versions (2.5, 3.0, 4.0) in your declarations. It is advised to use the version-less xsd so that you always use the latest versions.

Comment: i fixed the xml and added my pom

Comment: If you create a war the file should be there, if you use other means to deploy your application it might depend. How do you deploy your application.

Comment: The file is there now, but I also got a SAXParseException:
Could not find declaration for element "mvc:annotation-driven".
I deploy my application by copying the generated war-file to tomcats /tomcat/webapps/ folder

Comment: Solved it looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406231/no-declaration-can-be-found-for-element-mvcannotation-driven. Thanks for the hint with the xsd versions.