# How to resolve XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException in Spring MVC while adding mvc:annotation-driven?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web, spring-data

Following is the error stack trace.

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 15 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 15; columnNumber: 27; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:annotation-driven'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:381)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4992)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5490)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 15; columnNumber: 27; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:annotation-driven'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:458)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3237)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1917)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:766)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2770)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:348)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    ... 22 more

Sep 09, 2014 12:08:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Sep 09, 2014 12:08:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/Project1] startup failed due to previous errors
Sep 09, 2014 12:08:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Sep 09, 2014 12:08:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:170)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:921)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:841)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:551)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5685)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Sep 09, 2014 12:08:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Volumes/Dev/ProjJars/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/docs
Sep 09, 2014 12:08:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /Volumes/Dev/ProjJars/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/docs has finished in 43 ms
Sep 09, 2014 12:08:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Volumes/Dev/ProjJars/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/examples
Sep 09, 2014 12:08:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Sep 09, 2014 12:08:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Sep 09, 2014 12:08:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@3e386455')
Sep 09, 2014 12:08:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /Volumes/Dev/ProjJars/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/examples has finished in 165 ms
Sep 09, 2014 12:08:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Volumes/Dev/ProjJars/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/host-manager
Sep 09, 2014 12:08:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /Volumes/Dev/ProjJars/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/host-manager has finished in 33 ms
Sep 09, 2014 12:08:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Volumes/Dev/ProjJars/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/manager
Sep 09, 2014 12:08:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /Volumes/Dev/ProjJars/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/manager has finished in 53 ms
Sep 09, 2014 12:08:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Volumes/Dev/ProjJars/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/ROOT
Sep 09, 2014 12:08:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /Volumes/Dev/ProjJars/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/ROOT has finished in 25 ms
Sep 09, 2014 12:08:42 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 09, 2014 12:08:42 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 09, 2014 12:08:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1567 ms
```

Following is my dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.Project.www" />

    <!-- Factory bean that creates the Mongo instance -->
    <bean id="mongo" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
        <property name="host" value="localhost" />
    </bean>

    <!-- MongoTemplate for connecting and quering the documents in the database -->
    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo" />
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="Proj" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Use this post processor to translate any MongoExceptions thrown in @Repository annotated classes -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />



    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp"
          p:suffix=".jsp" /> 

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesViewResolver"/>

    <bean class=
    "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
  <property name="definitions">
    <list>
      <value>/WEB-INF/views/views.xml</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

And this is how my pom.xml looks

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.Project.www</groupId>
    <artifactId>Project</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Project</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- <plugin>
            <configuration>
             <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
            </configuration>
            </plugin> -->
        </plugins>
        <!-- <finalName>HelloSpringWithMongoDB</finalName> -->
    </build>
</project>
```

I have added few new things in XML namespace in Schema location based on other answers in stackoverflow. It would be really helpful if some one could verify and cross check it for me.

**Solution :**

After 20 hours of struggle I resolved the issue by  changing the xsd as follows.
Source : [no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:annotation-driven'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406231/no-declaration-can-be-found-for-element-mvcannotation-driven)

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:beans="http://springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd       
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">
```

Answer (score 2):

You miss the line:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/
```

in your beans configuration:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.0.xsd">
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I still get the same error. Any other suggestions.

Comment: You have the spring-mvc.jar in version 3.2 in your classpath?

Comment: I selected my prject in Eclipse and clicked "java Built path" and then "Libraries. "Please confirm if this is classpath. If yes, then I have Spring 4.0 in classpath. I have mentioned 4.0 in pom.xml. But there is no 3.2 in libraries.

Comment: @user3705478 Then change the version number in your context file to 4.0! See my updated answer.

Comment: Don't use version numbers... It is preferred to use the versionless xsd. That will always point to the most recent xsd available on the classpath.

Comment: Now I get error as "cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:annotation-
 driven'."

Comment: @M.Deinum So if it needs to be versionless, how should the declaration look like?

Comment: @user3705478 Versionless meas you have to remove the versionnumber before`.xsd`

Comment: So it should look like http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-.xsd  or
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
for each versioned schema declaration.

Comment: @user3705478 the second one is ok.

Comment: This is how my declaration looks
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd       
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd"> Still I get the same error.

Comment: I see this line as INFO in stacktrace   "lib/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class"

Comment: @user3705478 please add the dependencies to your question so we can try it by our own.

Comment: @user3705478 Where do run the application? On a tomcat?

Comment: Yes I run in tomcat 7 and I have also added pom.xml in question details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61043/discussion-between-user3705478-and-jens).

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA considers the two lines duplicate and automatically removes it.