# The requested resource is not available error in Spring Web MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, tomcat7

**Dear Altruist,**

I am trying to run Spring Web MVC HelloWeb project but it always shows "The requested resource is not available" error.
Would you please help me regarding this problem?

**Project Structure:**

[image]

**web.xml file:**

[image]

**HelloWeb-servlet.xml file:**

[image]

**HelloController.java file:**

[image]

Comment: Are you getting tomcat/other homepage at `localhost:8080`? Sometimes eclipse wont give you tomcat webapps.

Comment: Yes, "localhost:8080" is showing Tomcat homepage properly...

Comment: "Run Project" means "Run on Server" option? Also what URL is displayed in browser? What happens, after starting tomcat, when you go to `http://localhost:8080/HelloWeb/hello'. ?

Comment: Are you using dynamic web project? Is all the libraries present in the class path? I think you should use maven or gradle to build the project.

Comment: I am trying to run with "localhost:8080/HelloWeb/hello" and it shows that error. 
And I am creating this project from eclipse >> "Dynamic Web Project". And All Spring libraries are present in /WEB_INF/lib folder.

Comment: Add `<mvc:annotation-config/>` in `helloweb-servlet` it will work fine

Comment: Showing compiled error: The prefix "mvc" for element "mvc:annotation-config" is not bound. @PrasannaKumar

Comment: You need to define the`xmlns:mvc` in xml header with mvc schema uri

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message it seems you do not have your context defined in Tomcat.

Include a file named context.xml, into the META-INF folder, with the content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Context path="/HelloWeb"/>
```

From the tomcat documentation:

[Tomcat Context Container Documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context)

> Individual Context elements may be explicitly defined:
>
> In an individual file at /META-INF/context.xml inside the application
>   files. Optionally (based on the Host's copyXML attribute) this may be
>   copied to $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/ and renamed to
>   application's base file name plus a ".xml" extension.

Also, return a ModelView object instead of a String  to get redirected to your home.jsp page.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
protected ModelAndView printHello(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("hello");

    return model;
}
```

Comment: I have included the context.xml file into META-INF folder but still same error occurred.

Comment: The implementation of `printHello` is correct. No need to change it into `ModelAndView` pattern. The string, `"hello"` it returns, is not just a string. It's a view name. Here it points to `hello.jsp`. But I don't know what causes the issue.

Comment: I have implemented ModelAndView pattern but still same issue. @alfcope

Answer (score 0):

Replace your beans tag like this.

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
```

Comment: Applied, but still same error...

`@Controller
public class HelloController{
 
 @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView printHello(HttpServletRequest request,
     HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
     ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("hello");
     return model;
 }

}`

Comment: try adding  <mvc:annotation-config/> in helloweb-servlet

Comment: Showing compiled error: The prefix "mvc" for element "mvc:annotation-config" is not bound. @jagga

Comment: see the edited answer. replace your code in helloweb-servlet

Comment: I have replaced my helloweb-servet.xml with your tag and after that it showing another compilation error in eclipse.
**"cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:annotation-config'."**

Comment: [this question can help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406231/no-declaration-can-be-found-for-element-mvcannotation-driven)

Comment: @Amit got the answer??

Comment: After replacing beans tag in "helloweb-servet.xml" Now compilation error is gone but still showing "The requested resource is not available" error after running...