# Downloading from external resources is disabled in hibernate dtd

Tags: download, configuration, resources, external, hibernate.cfg.xml

While I am trying to do hibernate configuration I put hibernate dtd in hibernate.cfg.xml file and it is showing an error that downloading from external resources is disabled. Can you please help me with this error?

[image]

[image]

I wanted to create a maven project with hibernate, so I am trying to do my hibernate configuration to do mapping.

Answer (score 40):

If you are using Eclipse :

Go to top bar : Window -> Preference -> Maven -> tick the option ('download artifact javadoc').

Thats is 'Apply & Close'.

Answer (score 13):

I was able to get this to work the the below option:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Any one looking for the same option in mac the path is
Eclipse -> Settings -> Maven -> tick the option ('download artifact javadoc')

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using Mac then follow**

- Eclipse Preferences
- Select Maven
- Make sure the select what see in the below picture
- Then Apply and Close

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
If you are encountering the 
"Downloading from external resources is disabled in Hibernate DTD" issue while 
using Eclipse, follow these steps to resolve it:

1. Navigate to the top bar and select "Window."

2. From the dropdown menu, choose "Preferences."

3. Within the Preferences window, locate and click on "Maven."

4. In the Maven preferences, find the option labeled "Download artifact javadoc."

5. Tick the checkbox next to "Download artifact javadoc" to enable the option.

6. After making the change, click on the "Apply & Close" button to save 
your preferences.

By enabling the "Download artifact javadoc" option in Maven preferences, 
you should address the issue of downloading from external resources being disabled 
in Hibernate DTD within Eclipse.
```