# spring-beans.xsd (Downloading external resources is disabled)

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

I created a Maven project and connected spring dependencies, then created the applicationContext.xml file, inserted the ready-made code to create this file, and an error appeared.[image]

The link to which the error indicates is working, I tried to change the link but the error remained hanging, in fact the code works but eclipse thinks that this is not so and writes on the highlighted red line (Downloading external resources is disabled)

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
</beans>```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Downloading from external resources is disabled in hibernate dtd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77252112/downloading-from-external-resources-is-disabled-in-hibernate-dtd)

Answer (score 0):

Go to windows>preferences>xml(wild web developer)(double click)>select download external resources like referenced DTD,XSD.
Now check your xml file your error will be disapppeared.